# Группировка элементов

Tags: java, java-stream

Основная задача найти сумму баланса для каждого пользователя.
Нужно использовать вспомогательный класс для группировки Pair.

Мой код:

```
public class SummingMethod {

    public static class User {

        private String name;

        private List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<>();

        public User(String name, List<Bill> bills) {
            this.name = name;
            this.bills = bills;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public List<Bill> getBills() {
            return bills;
        }
    }

    public static class Bill {

        private int balance;

        public Bill(int balance) {
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        public int getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }
    }

    private static class Pair {
        private User user;
        private Bill bill;

        public Pair(User user, Bill bill) {
            this.user = user;
            this.bill = bill;
        }

        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public Bill getBill() {
            return bill;
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> summing(List<User> users) {
        List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        n -> n %= 2,
                        Collectors.summingInt(n -> n )
                )).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));

    }
}
```

мой тест:

```
public class SummingMethodTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Bill b1 = new Bill(1);
        Bill b2 = new Bill(2);
        Bill b3 = new Bill(3);
        Bill b4 = new Bill(4);
        Bill b5 = new Bill(5);
        Bill b6 = new Bill(6);
        User u1 = new User("u1", List.of(b1));
        User u2 = new User("u2", List.of(b2, b3));
        User u3 = new User("u3", List.of(b4, b5, b6));
        Map<String, Integer> expect = Map.of(
                "u1", 1,
                "u2", 5,
                "u3", 15
        );
        assertEquals(expect, SummingMethod.summing(List.of(u1, u2, u3)));
    }

}
```

что нужно сделать чтобы код работал как надо?

Comment: Измените метод `summing`, сейчас в нем решение от другой задачи, которое не подходит к текущей.

Answer (score 0):

Замечания по вопросу:

- Представленный метод `summing` не будет компилироваться, так как он не возвращает мапу-результат.
- Использование класса `Pair` не является необходимым для решения данной задачи даже для промежуточных вычислений суммарного баланса

Для решения данной задачи может оказаться проще воспользоваться коллектором `Collectors.toMap` вместо привычного `Collectors.groupingBy`

```java
public static Map<String, Integer> summing(List<User> users) {
    return users.stream() // Stream<User>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            User::getName,        // ключ: имя пользователя
            u -> u.getBills().stream().mapToInt(Bill::getBalance).sum(), // значение: суммарный баланс
            (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2,  // для решения возможных конфликтов
            LinkedHashMap::new    // для поддержания порядка вставки в мапу
        ));
}
```